# undefined LLVM IR depending on array size

Tags: arrays, llvm, undefined-behavior, memcpy, llvm-ir

I see an undefined behaviour depending on the size of the local array.
For the code below:

```
    int wbExecute_simple(char nInput, char add_pattern)
    {
        char test_array[4] = { 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd };
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            test_array[i] ^= nInput;
        }
        return (test_array[nInput] + add_pattern);
    }
```

The LLVM IR representation for the first line is:

```
    lbl_0_wb3954:
    %local_0_wb3954 = alloca [4 x i8], align 1
    %local_1_wb3954 = bitcast [4 x i8]* %local_0_wb3954 to i32*, !dbg !7
    %local_2_wb3954 = bitcast [4 x i8]* @global_0_wb3954 to i32*
    %local_3_wb3954 = load i32* %local_2_wb3954, align 1, !dbg !7
    store i32 %local_3_wb3954, i32* %local_1_wb3954, align 1, !dbg !7
    br label %lbl_1_wb3954, !dbg !8
```

Having the array size of 2 also produces similar result. But, changing the size of array from 4 to 3 as below,

```
    int wbExecute_simple(char nInput, char add_pattern)
    {
        char test_array[3] = { 0xa, 0xb, 0xc };
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < 3; ++i)
        {
        test_array[i] ^= nInput;
        }
        return (test_array[nInput] + add_pattern);
    }
```

yields

```
    define i32 @wbExecute_simple(i8 signext %nInput, i8 signext %add_pattern) #0 {
        lbl_0_wb3954:
        %local_0_wb3954 = alloca [3 x i8], align 1
        %local_1_wb3954 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i8]* %local_0_wb3954, i32 0, i32 0, !dbg !7
        %local_2_wb3954 = getelementptr [3 x i8]* @global_0_wb3954, i32 0, i32 0
        call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i32(i8* %local_1_wb3954, i8* %local_2_wb3954, i32 3, i32 1, i1 false), !dbg !7
        br label %lbl_1_wb3954, !dbg !8
```

Is there any optimisation flag to make the LLVM IR for arrays of both size to be the same?

Comment: Which flags are you passing to the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by undefined behaviour. This looks like a legitimate compiler optimization.

When the array has length 4, the compiler replaces copying the array by copying a single integer, because that has size 4 too, and can be done in a single operation. I assume for size two it will copy a 16-bit integer.

Your system will probably not support any 24-bit integers, so the compiler decided not to optimize this for size 3 and keep the `memcpy` intrinsic. Note that without an "int24" type supported by the processor and memory system, this optimization would not make sense for a size 3 array. There may be further optimizations in the compiler backend to improve the remaining memcpy intrinsic, depending on whether it makes sense on the target machine.

I will comment the generated IR to clarify what the code does:

```
   lbl_0_wb3954:
    // allocate the local array
    %local_0_wb3954 = alloca [4 x i8], align 1
    // cast the address of the local array to an integer pointer
    %local_1_wb3954 = bitcast [4 x i8]* %local_0_wb3954 to i32*, !dbg !7
    // cast the address of the constant array {  0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd } to an integer pointer
    %local_2_wb3954 = bitcast [4 x i8]* @global_0_wb3954 to i32*
    // load the constant array as a 32 bit integer
    %local_3_wb3954 = load i32* %local_2_wb3954, align 1, !dbg !7
    // store the value to the local array
    store i32 %local_3_wb3954, i32* %local_1_wb3954, align 1, !dbg !7
    br label %lbl_1_wb3954, !dbg !8
```

I do not think this type of optimization can be easily forced for length 3.

Passing -O2 for example will cause complete unrolling of the length 3 loop and remove the static initialization in favor of inlining the constants `0xa`, `0xb`, and `0xc` into the [code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%0A++++int+wbExecute_simple(char+nInput,+char+add_pattern)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++char+test_array%5B3%5D+%3D+%7B+0xa,+0xb,+0xc+%7D%3B%0A++++++++int+i+%3D+0%3B%0A++++++++for+(%3B+i+%3C+3%3B+%2B%2Bi)%0A++++++++%7B%0A++++++++test_array%5Bi%5D+%5E%3D+nInput%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++++++return+(test_array%5BnInput%5D+%2B+add_pattern)%3B%0A++++%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2+-emit-llvm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), the code for size four looks analogously.

```
  %3 = alloca [3 x i8], align 1
  // compute address of first array element
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i8], [3 x i8]* %3, i64 0, i64 0, !dbg !22
  // compute 0xa ^ nInput;
  %5 = xor i8 %0, 10, !dbg !25
  // store the result
  store i8 %5, i8* %4, align 1, !dbg !25, !tbaa !29

  // do the same for the second and third elements
  %6 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i8], [3 x i8]* %3, i64 0, i64 1, !dbg !32
  %7 = xor i8 %0, 11, !dbg !25
  store i8 %7, i8* %6, align 1, !dbg !25, !tbaa !29
  %8 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x i8], [3 x i8]* %3, i64 0, i64 2, !dbg !32
  %9 = xor i8 %0, 12, !dbg !25
  store i8 %9, i8* %8, align 1, !dbg !25, !tbaa !29
```